# Local history / revisions for development files

Tags: controls, history, local, revision

In eclipse you have local history, I was wondering if there is some software that can keep track of file history similar to this but without using eclipse.

Basically I want to be able to track my history and view it from any editor for PHP projects.

I'm already using SVN version control but I wish to have local history also.

Comment: Hmm... why not just create local SVN repo (it's rather easy)? And if you want to track history locally and in the same time to use remote SVN server you probably should switch to DVCS such as `mercurial` or `git`. In this case you can `clone` the repo and track local changes. And when you want you can `push` those changes back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to ask a similar question, which I reproduce here for search purposes (the answer is below) :

---

I have a working copy of the source of a project using subversion.  Now, suppose I have two different issues to fix on the same file while I don't have access to the svn server for whatever reason.  I don't want the two fixes to be mixed up in a global patch : for the sake of clarity I would like to have a patch for each fix.  So I would like to be able to "svn diff" between the original revision, the firstly modified revision and the last revision, which have not been committed to the server — or alternatively said, to be able to commit each revision independently.

How do you do that ?  Is there a way to flag revisions locally with svn ?

---

Then I found this question and maverick's reply triggered a new keyword : "clone".  Looking for "svn clone" I found out that a good answer could be to use "git-svn" (NB : a dash for the name, but no dash for the command : "git svn"), then use git locally.  I let you google on that, but to make things short :

```
git svn --username=skippy clone http://svn.example.org/projects/myproject -T trunk localdir
```

Apply first patch :

```
git add path/to/modified/file
git commit
```

Apply second patch :

```
git add path/to/modified/file
git commit
```

Then get your revision IDs :

```
git log --oneline|head
```

And to see modifications added by revision a1b2c3 :

```
git diff a1b2c3d{^,}
```